# This record was modified by Same User during your edit session

Tags: lightning, opportunity

In my org when i am editing and saving few opportunities i am getting error :
This record was modified by (Same User) during your edit session. Make a note of the data you entered, then reload the record and enter your updates again.

Facts:
1)I tired Reloading the record numerous times ...didn't work.
2)This problem is  for few opportunity records
3)This problem is only in LEX..If i edit and save those records in classic..not getting any error.

From these facts can anyone suggest the probable cause. I understand the concept of collision but probable cause like scheduled job are ruled out as it works in classic.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Dnyaneshwar, I am facing exactly the same issue.  Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out.  In my case, we had a VF page embedded on the page layout which was doing an update on the Opportunity to count the number of Opp Contact Roles (SFDC does not allow you to create a roll up summary field on this for some reason, and you can't write triggers for OppContactRole object).  In Classic, when you click 'Edit', it takes you straight to the Edit page.  But in LEX, *it first refreshes the page*, and then takes you to the Edit page.  Because of our VF page, this results in the Opportunity being updated at around the same time that the Edit page comes up.  So when you try and save, you get the 'record was modified error'.

Comment: FYI, in general it is a bad idea for a component on a record to trigger a DML write on load, especially on the same record.

Comment: @Charles T, yes I agree, but we were forced to do this because of the inflexibility with Opp Contact Roles, and our validation rule based on number of Opp Contact Roles.